# How to access Oracle DB Link in Django models?

Tags: python, django

Im trying to access table from different databases using database Link. Im getting error `database link not found`

My model looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Customer(models.Model):
    cust_num = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    customer_number = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    class Meta:
        db_table = '\"MY_SCHEMA\".\"TABLE_NAME\"@\"OTHER_DB\"'
        managed = False
```

And im getting this error while trying to access it through Python Django shell

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-04054: database link MY_SCHEMA.CUST_NUM does not exist
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not a good way to do that.

you have to add the config for the second database in your settings:

```py
DATABASES = {
    "default": {...},
    "OTHER_DB": {...},
}
```

You create your model normally with the table name in your OTHER_DB

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Customer(models.Model):
    cust_num = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    customer_number = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'TABLE_NAME'
        managed = False
```

And when you have access to the db, you can use the `using` param for choosing the good DB:

```py
Customer.objects.using("OTHER_DB").all()
```

You can find more information about multi databases management in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Currently, the Oracle version of OTHER_DB still 11g and it is not compatible with the current CX_Oracle of my Django project (minimum requirement needs Oracle 19c). I need to access the table via DB link

Comment: I would upgrade to a newer version. You can connect from a 18c or 19c client to a 11g database.